# How to renew Azure resources privilege identity management roles programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-automation, pim

I have a requirement to automate renewal of all the soon to be expiring azure resources PIM role but it seems there is no PowerShell module available at this moment for the PIM.

I also tried exploring rest api option but it appears that there is no rest end point available but I found graph api endpoints which seems to be supporting this feature but as per Microsoft documentation it doesn't support access via service principal so not sure how to proceed further on this.

Did anyone try this before, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share the Microsoft documentation link which you are referring to ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/privilegedroleassignment-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http